# Going back to Main Activity on Android app with back key to see user score

Tags: java, android, android-activity, back, activity-finish

Hopefully I can get some advice on this.

My program has a sprite that, when hit/clicked, a score is tallied on screen.  When the game is over (time runs out), I want the user to be able to press the back key on their phone to go back to the main/start screen/activity where they began the game, but it will also show their score (how many hits).

I'm struggling to figure out how to get it to go back with the back key press.  I can figure out the high score bit at a later date if need be.  I just want to get back to that start screen.

UPDATE:

I think it may have something to do with my manifest as to why it's not working.  I've tried to add the 'GameView' class to the manifest but it won't accept it.  It says it has no default constructor.  Any ideas?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="cct.mad.lab.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
     </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameView"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

My GameView code is below:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

/* Member (state) fields   */
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private Paint paint; //Reference a paint object 
/** The drawable to use as the background of the animation canvas */
private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
// For creating the game Sprite
private Sprite sprite;
// For recording the number of hits
private int hitCount;
// To track if a game is over
private boolean gameOver;
// To play sound
private SoundPlayer sound;

//int backButtonCount = 0;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Focus must be on GameView so that events can be handled.
    this.setFocusable(true);
    // For intercepting events on the surface.
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    // Background image added
    mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.half_moon);

    //sound = new SoundPlayer(this);

}
 /* Called immediately after the surface created */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // We can now safely setup the game start the game loop.
    ResetGame();//Set up a new game up - could be called by a 'play again option'
    mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
    gameLoopThread.running = true;
    gameLoopThread.start();
}



// For the countdown timer
private long startTime; // Timer to count down from
private final long interval = 1 * 1000; // 1 sec interval
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // Reference to the class
private boolean timerRunning = false;
private String displayTime; // To display the time on the screen


//To initialise/reset game
private void ResetGame(){
    /* Set paint details */
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    hitCount = 0;
    // Set timer
    startTime = 10; // Start at 10s to count down
    // Create new object - convert startTime to milliseconds
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime*1000, interval);
    countDownTimer.start(); // Start the time running
    timerRunning = true;
    gameOver = false;


}

// Countdown Timer - private class
private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer (long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        //displayTime = "Time is up!";
        timerRunning = false;
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        gameOver = true;
    }
    public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
        displayTime = " " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
    }
}


//This class updates and manages the assets prior to drawing - called from the Thread
public void update(){

    sprite.update();

}
/**
 * To draw the game to the screen
 * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
 */
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Draw all the objects on the canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);

    if (!gameOver) {
        sprite.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawText("Time Remaining: " + displayTime, 35, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Number of hits: " + hitCount, 250, 50, paint);
    } else
        canvas.drawText("Game Over!", 185, 100, paint);
        canvas.drawText("To go back to the main menu, press the 'back' key", 15, 150, paint);


}

//To be used if we need to find where screen was touched
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            // This just renews the sprite for now
            sprite = new Sprite(this);
            //sound.playZapSound();
            hitCount++;

        }
    return true;
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    gameLoopThread.running = false;

    // Shut down the game loop thread cleanly.
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            gameLoopThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public void getHitCount() {



}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

}
```

My MainActivity is below:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

private static final int SCORE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;// The request code for the intent

TextView tvScore;
String score;
Intent gameIntent;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_start);
}

public void startGame(View v){
    gameIntent = new Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(gameIntent, SCORE_REQUEST_CODE );  
}
/* Create Options Menu */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

// Respond to item selected on OPTIONS MENU
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    //put data in Intent
    case R.id.easy:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Easy chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.medium:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Medium chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.hard:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hard chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.other:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Other chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent retIntent) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (retIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) {
                int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
                tvScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));
            }
        }   
    }

}


}
```

As always, any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try to override the onBackPressed() of activity and start the activity with the help of intent which may provide you desired effect, also comment the super.onBackPressed() of onBackPressed()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onBackPressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i= new Intent(your_present_activity.this,the_activity_you_want_to_jump_to.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

You can take your score to Main.class by using newintent.putExtra(name,"key");

Comment: Is there somewhere in particular I should put this as the override is coming up with an error - 'Method does not override method from its superclass'

Comment: Call super.onBackPressed(); do not remove @override.

Comment: Adding that gives the error - 'Cannot resolve method 'onBackPressed()''

Comment: edited answer .....(  this is working fine for me .. try this once.) add  super.onBackPressed(); if still not working

Comment: It just doesn't seem to like any of it for me.  Getting 'cannot resolve' errors on 'EffectActivity', 'startActivity' and on 'finish'

Comment: EffectActivity=your_present_activity,  startActivity=the_activity_you_want_to_jump_to  ( rename according to your project)

Comment: Oh I see.  However, that now says 'Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent....'.  And it still says that it cannot resolve methods 'startActivity(i)', and 'finish()'

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that my issue with the back button not working was all down to my else statement in the doDraw method not having curly braces around the two statements.  Added those and it works fine.  The surfaceDestroyed method gets called automatically when the back button is pressed as this stops the gameLoopThread class.

Thanks for everyone trying to help me.